# in android, how to get which pointer up in ACTION_POINTER_UP event?

Tags: android, touch

Hi,

In android,

```
first pointer down ----> ACTION_DOWN

second pointer down ----> ACTION_POINTER_DOWN / ACTION_POINTER_1_DOWN

first / second pointer release ----> ACTION_POINTER_UP / ACTION_POINTER_1_UP
```

Well, how to get which pointer (first or second) release in `ACTION_POINTER_UP` event?

Thanks.Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If your problem is solved, Change your comment to answer or close this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i found it, can use `getActionIndex()` to get which pointer up, is start be supported by api level 8.